# Having some issues with setting up permissions on my web server

Tags: linux, permissions

My setup is the following:

```
Multiple users coding for the one website
Each user has their own username/group
Websites are located in /usr/local/ourcompany/websites/sitename/*
```

`./websites/` is owned by `me:ourcompany`. I set this folder and all it's subfolders to be writable by group. `chmod g+ws websites`

This takes care of most the permission issues. It allows everyone in the `ourcompany` group to edit the website files. The problem is when uploading files via PHP.

PHP is running as `www-data`. This seems to break the setuid group writable setting.

I'm running Nginx, if that's relevant...

Any tips?

Comment: Just a comment as I can't offer a solution: The issue is that, although you've got group-sticky on the folders, that doesn't apply to newly created files, which take on the system-wide umask. Most common linuxes have the umask set at 0022 (= rwxr-xr-x). You could set that to 0002 (= rwxrwxr-x), But I'm going to staple the words 'Massive Security Hole' to that as a warning. It's not possible to set per-directory umasks. :)

Answer (score 0):

I will do it this way:

1- Keep the working permissions as you have it.

2- Upload the files via PHP to a different (temporary) directory. This temp directory should be writable by www-data user.

3- Write a simple script to copy/move the uploaded files from the temp directory to the desired path `/usr/local/ourcompany/websites/sitename/*`. Then, you can chown/chmod the new files to make sure the permissions are preserved as you upload more files. This script will be executed as root as explained in the next point.

4- Add the www-data user to sudoers file. Use `sudo visudo` to edit it. So, the www-data user will execute the shell script (created in point 3) as super user without a password. You need to name the script in the sudoers file to restrict this permission to this signle shell script.

Answer (score 0):

You PHP upload script is probably a very specific one, like /upload/up_script.php

In which case, I would create a specific location in the nginx's config, and execute those queries with a php5-cgi process runned by a member of "ourcompany" (instead of www-data).
The rest of the code can (should) still be executed by a user that doesn't have write permissions on the website files.